# R, improving speed of sorting

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, sorting

I am simulating ~30 dependent random variables, let let's say 500K times. Then I am summing all random variables to get my desired results. I want to find out the 99.5% percentile of this sum which is easily done. In addition, I want to get all adjacent scenarios to the 99.5% realisation on Random Variable level. That is, for the 99.499%-percentile i want to know what the different realisations were for each random variable. Below a stylized example of a code that does this. However, it turns out that the "order" function takes quite some time. Any suggestions on how to minimize runtime of the code below? It might not seem to be an issue in this particular example but I will need to do the above about 500 times.

```
require("MASS")

  #Parameters to run
  n=30
  N_simulations=500000
  Percentile=0.995
  window_size=101

  #Preparing multivariate normal parameters
  cov_matrix<-matrix(0.5,n,n)
  diag(cov_matrix)<-1
  mu<-rep(0,30)


  #running the simulation
  simulation_matrix<-t(mvrnorm(n=N_simulations, mu=mu, Sigma= cov_matrix)) #RVs as rows and simulations as columns
  losses<-colSums(simulation_matrix)
  VaR<-quantile(losses,probs=0.995)

  #Method 1 - using the order function to get adjacent scenarios
  unsorted_losses<-cbind(seq(1:N_simulations),losses)
  sorted_losses<-unsorted_losses[order(unsorted_losses[,2],decreasing=FALSE),]

  sorted_scenario<-N_simulations*Percentile 
  window<-seq(-(window_size-1)/2,(window_size-1)/2,1)
  window<-sorted_scenario+window 
  scenarios<-as.vector(sorted_losses[window,1])  # gives all the adjacent scenarios


   #Method 2 - using partial sort function (does not work properly when duplicate values)
  names(unsorted_losses)<-seq(1:N_simulations)
  z=2*(1-Percentile)*N_simulations
  a<-sort(-unsorted_losses,partial=1:z)
  sorted_losses<- - a[1:z] #highest loss to smallest loss

  u<-names(unsorted_losses[match(sorted_losses,unsorted_losses)]) #getting the rownames in unsorted losses
  names(sorted_losses)<-u

  sorted_scenario<-N_simulations-N_simulations*Percentile
  window<-seq(-(window_size-1)/2,(window_size-1)/2,1)
  window<-sorted_scenario+window #gives the r
  scenarios<-as.numeric(names(sorted_losses[window]))  # gives all the adjacent scenarios from the rownames

# code proposed by Stackoverflow users
  window_size<-1001
  percentile_step<-1/N_simulations
  window<-seq(-(window_size-1)/2,(window_size-1)/2,1)
  percentiles<-window*percentile_step*Percentile+Percentile
  window_losses<-quantile(losses,probs=percentiles,type=3)

  a<-losses[losses %in% window_losses] # returns only 997 TRUE, not 1001!!
```

Comment: Is it necessary to sort at all? if you have this in a data.frame, can you just select those rows where the losses are in the desired quantile range?

Comment: Using `method = "radix"` seems to speed things up considerably for me.

Comment: I am going to second @Shape's idea.  You can find the quantile quickly because quick-select is very efficient.  Do this twice find a narrow quantile range, then select that out of your data (single scan of your data), then sort a tiny number of records and do what you like.